# getting a dictionary of int to str from a filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing programming for the first time and I have exam next week. We are diong python in the course (Python 3)

I need help on this question from past exams on  filename. I hardly understood filenames in how to call them. I know the basic stuff of a file. In how to readline skip a line. But nothing hard.

So I have a filename filled with a menu and I want to dictionary from it. We are given this example only. I have no clue whats it spewing it or what I have to do.

This is the example provided

```
def read_menu(menu_file):   

 '''(file open for reading) -> dict of int to str

    Read menu_file; each menu item in the restaurant has a number and a name.
    The resulting dictionary maps numbers to names.

    Sample input file:
       1 Fried rice
       2 Plain white rice
       3 Plain brown rice
      10 Chive dumpling (steamed)
      11 Pork and shrimp dumpling (steamed)
      12 Mushroom dumpling (steamed)
      13 Pork and bitter melon dumpling (steamed)
      14 Cherry dumpling (steamed)
      20 Pork and shrimp dumpling (fried)
      21 Pork dumpling (fried)
     101 Bubble tea
     102 Ice tea
 '''
```

Any help/ hints or solutions with what you did would be really helpful. Like I dont want just the code like I want to know the thinking behind it.

When I read this question I thought you are calling a number and want that value or something. and I think that was wrong

Comment: Do you have a little more information on what aspect of this problem is puzzling for you? Do you understand what a dictionary is? Do you understand how to add values to it? Do you understand, given a line of text like the examples, how to turn it into a key-value pair? Do you understand how to iterate over a file as a series of lines?

Comment: Oh, also, is it clear that the first line of the docstring is meant to be a specification for the function? That's probably the most confusing part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work fine.

```
def read_menu(menu_file):
    d = dict()
    with open(menu_file) as menu_text:
         lines = menu_text.readlines()
         for line in lines:
             w = line.split()
             try: d[int(w[0])] = ' '.join(w[1:])
             except: pass
    return d
```

On your test input:

```
>>> read_menu("menu.txt")
{1: 'Fried rice', 2: 'Plain white rice', 3: 'Plain brown rice', 101: 'Bubble tea
', 102: 'Ice tea', 10: 'Chive dumpling (steamed)', 11: 'Pork and shrimp dumpling
 (steamed)', 12: 'Mushroom dumpling (steamed)', 13: 'Pork and bitter melon dumpl
ing (steamed)', 14: 'Cherry dumpling (steamed)', 20: 'Pork and shrimp dumpling (
fried)', 21: 'Pork dumpling (fried)'}
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for hints and explanation, not working code.